# Embeddinator 4000: Unable to find Invoker for type

Tags: android, .net, embeddinator

I'm trying to get C# to java callbacks working. I followed the "interface" section in this guide: https://mono.github.io/Embeddinator-4000/android-callbacks.html

The problem is that i get an error in Android Studio:

> FATAL UNHANDLED
>   EXCEPTION: System.NotSupportedException: Unable to find Invoker for
>   type 'MyProject.Interfaces.ICallback'. Was it linked away?

I'm using Android Studio 3.0

Why is my invoker not found? I checked the guide multiple times but i can't find what i forgot or what i did wrong

My .Net code:

```
namespace MyProject.Classes
{
   [Register("mono.embeddinator.android.CallbackTester")]
   public class CallbackTester : Java.Lang.Object
   {
      //callback test method
      [Export("process")]
      public static void Process(ICallback callback)
      {
         callback.OnSuccess("this is a string defined in C#");
      }

      //callback test method
      [Export("processno2")]
      public void Processno2(ICallback callback)
      {
         callback.OnSuccess("this is a string defined in C#");
      }
   }
}
```

.NET interface:

```
namespace MyProject.Interfaces
{
    [Register("mono.embeddinator.android.ICallback")]
    public interface ICallback : IJavaObject
    {
      [Export("onSuccess")]
      void OnSuccess(string test);
    } 
}
```

Java interface: (= .java file defined in visual studio)

```
package mono.embeddinator.android;

public interface ICallback
{
     void onSuccess(String test);
}
```

Invoker:

```
namespace MyProject.Invokers
{
   class ICallbackInvoker : Java.Lang.Object, ICallback
   {
    IntPtr class_ref, id_onSuccess;

    public ICallbackInvoker(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(handle, transfer)
    {
        IntPtr lref = JNIEnv.GetObjectClass(Handle);
        class_ref = JNIEnv.NewGlobalRef(lref);
        JNIEnv.DeleteLocalRef(lref);
    }

    protected override Type ThresholdType
    {
        get { return typeof(ICallbackInvoker); }
    }

    protected override IntPtr ThresholdClass
    {
        get { return class_ref; }
    }

    public void OnSuccess(string test)
    {
        if (id_onSuccess == IntPtr.Zero)
            id_onSuccess = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(class_ref, "onSuccess", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
        JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod(Handle, id_onSuccess, new JValue(new Java.Lang.String(test)));
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (class_ref != IntPtr.Zero)
            JNIEnv.DeleteGlobalRef(class_ref);
        class_ref = IntPtr.Zero;

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! Everything had to be under the same namespace